# SwiftUI List using a filter, running into state update problems

Tags: swiftui

It's a little bit hard to explain what the problem is. It might be easiest to just run the code, and edit one of the models and then see what happens to its detail view. But I'll try to explain :)

I have a view where I show a list of computers, split into two sections based on a field in the Computer model. You can tap on a computer to show its detail screen, which has a button to edit the computer.

The problem happens when you edit the isLaptop boolean. So let's say you open the iMac, change isLaptop to true, and save the form. The detail screen still says "This is not a laptop", even though now it *should* say "This is a laptop". When you pop back to the list view, you will see that the list updated correctly, and that the iMac moved into the Laptops section.

My guess is that as soon as I edit the isLaptop field, that the `DetailView` basically becomes an orphan since the `ContentView` recreated its body, the list changed because of the filter, and now the `DetailView` is not "linked" anymore to what's already on screen. I thought adding `.id(computer.id)` to the `NavigationLink` would help, but sadly it does not.

So, how can make this work as expected, so that the filtered list with its two sections works, but when you change the field that is filtered on, subviews also get recreated correctly as expected?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Computer: Identifiable {
  var id: Int
  var name: String
  var isLaptop: Bool
}

class Store: ObservableObject {
  @Published var computers: [Computer] = [
    Computer(id: 0, name: "Macbook", isLaptop: true),
    Computer(id: 1, name: "iMac", isLaptop: false),
  ]
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var store: Store

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        Section(header: Text("Laptops")) {
          ForEach(store.computers.filter { $0.isLaptop == true }) { computer in
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(computer: computer)) {
              Text(computer.name)
            }
          }
        }

        Section(header: Text("Other computers")) {
          ForEach(store.computers.filter { $0.isLaptop == false }) { computer in
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(computer: computer)) {
              Text(computer.name)
            }
          }
        }
      }
      .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
      .navigationBarTitle("Computers")
    }
  }
}

struct DetailView: View {
  let computer: Computer

  @EnvironmentObject private var store: Store
  @State private var editing = false

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(computer.name)
      Text(computer.isLaptop ? "This is a laptop" : "This is not a laptop")
    }
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Edit") {
      self.editing = true
    })
    .sheet(isPresented: $editing) {
      FormView(computer: self.computer)
        .environmentObject(self.store)
    }
  }
}

struct FormView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var store: Store
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
  @State private var computer: Computer

  init(computer: Computer) {
    _computer = State(initialValue: computer)
  }

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Form {
        TextField("Name", text: $computer.name)
        Toggle("Is Laptop", isOn: $computer.isLaptop)
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("Edit Computer")
      .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Save") {
        self.store.computers = self.store.computers.filter { $0.id != self.computer.id } + [self.computer]
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
      })
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I managed to find a workaround:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var store: Store

  @State private var selected: Int?

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        List {
          Section(header: Text("Laptops")) {
            ForEach(store.computers.filter { $0.isLaptop == true }) { computer in
              Button(computer.name) {
                self.selected = computer.id
              }
            }
          }

          Section(header: Text("Other computers")) {
            ForEach(store.computers.filter { $0.isLaptop == false }) { computer in
              Button(computer.name) {
                self.selected = computer.id
              }
            }
          }
        }

        ForEach(store.computers) { computer in
          NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(computer: computer), tag: computer.id, selection: self.$selected) {
            EmptyView()
          }
        }
      }
      .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
      .navigationBarTitle("Computers")
    }
  }
}
```

Sadly these kinds of NavigationLinks behave kinda bad on the simulator, but it's fine on the device and the best I would come up with ‍♂️